# Capture screenshot of active window?

Tags: c#, screenshot, active-window

I am making a screen capturing application and everything is going fine.  All I need to do is capture the active window and take a screenshot of this active window.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Does "active window" mean the active window of YOUR app or the window that would be active if your app was hidden?

Comment: If you want a screenshot of all your monitors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847637/take-screenshot-of-multiple-desktops-of-all-visible-applications-and-forms

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
// capture entire screen, and save it to a file
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
// display image in a Picture control named imageDisplay
this.imageDisplay.Image = img;
// capture this window, and save it
sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"C:\\temp2.gif",ImageFormat.Gif);
```

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/

Comment: I already know how to capture a standard screenshot.  I just need to know how to capture the active window.

Comment: @joe i get a GDI+ error when trying to run above code. the error occurs in the ScreenCpature class at saving images.

Comment: Excellent!  I wanted to capture the content of a panel in my app.  So I did  sc.CaptureWindowToFile(panel1.Handle, "c:\temp.jpg", imageformat.jpg)  and voila!

Comment: I know this answer is from 2009, but still... saving a desktop in a 256-colour format? Tsk. Even jpeg loses less quality than that. Nowadays, just use png.

Comment: On HD resolution with zoomed Windows Interface elements, this class doesn't capture the whole screen.

Comment: Error on "ScreenCapture"

Comment: It would be great to include the usings and references for this solution.

Comment: The ScreenCapture feature is only supported for mobile devices running Windows Phone 8.1. This API is not supported on Windows 10.

Comment: @NareshRavlani: Yeah, on window10 i got black image only

Comment: When using this solution on windows 10, it works perfectly for anything but web browsers...

Answer (score 252):

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
         g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

for capturing current window use

```
 Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
 using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
 {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left,bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("C://test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 }
```

Comment: Neat! I though you would have to use the WinAPI. Do you know if this is implemented on Mono?

Comment: This just gives me a normal screenshot.  Don't I have to use the WinAPI?

Comment: Hi can i know how to do screen capture in vb web form aspx?

Comment: Hi @benylim, take a look to this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701798/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-web-page) and this
(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxjscript/thread/e64c562d-20cd-43b1-b13f-b12f09969619), hope this helps

Comment: Isitz only can do with java script?

Comment: I don't think there are ways to do this without js or ActivX

Comment: Hmm.. because i dont really understand it

Comment: this is awesome.  Taking screenshots of IE 10 doesn't work using GDI32 - the browser content is blank in the window - but this works like a champ.  And uses .NET.  Goodbye GDI32!!

Comment: This works but the resulting image is a bit too big. Eg if my form is full screen, I'll end up with some black borders on all sides, and  `form.Bounds.Location` gives me `(-8, -8)` instead of `(0, 0)`.

Comment: If you're getting a screenshot that is just slightly too large, the comments in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48041649/17142802) help ensure the screen size is correct.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a snippet to capture either the desktop or the active window.
It has no reference to Windows Forms.

```
public class ScreenCapture
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Rect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }   

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

    public static Image CaptureDesktop()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(GetDesktopWindow());
    }

    public static Bitmap CaptureActiveWindow()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(GetForegroundWindow());
    }

    public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        var rect = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);
        var bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
        var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

How to capture the whole screen:

```
var image = ScreenCapture.CaptureDesktop();
image.Save(@"C:\temp\snippetsource.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

How to capture the active window:

```
var image = ScreenCapture.CaptureActiveWindow();
image.Save(@"C:\temp\snippetsource.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Originally found here: [http://www.snippetsource.net/Snippet/158/capture-screenshot-in-c](http://web.archive.org/web/20161116203653/http://www.snippetsource.net/Snippet/158/capture-screenshot-in-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian for this great snippet. It helped me a lot!

Comment: This works great but does not work if the user has scaling set on that display (i.e., 125% cuts off the left and bottom sides)

Comment: The library `System.Drawing.Common` is needed for this.

Answer (score 31):

I suggest next solution for capturing any current active window (not only our C# application) or entire screen with cursor position determination relative to left-top corner of window or screen respectively:

```
public enum enmScreenCaptureMode
{
    Screen,
    Window
}

class ScreenCapturer
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Rect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    public Bitmap Capture(enmScreenCaptureMode screenCaptureMode = enmScreenCaptureMode.Window)
    {
        Rectangle bounds;

        if (screenCaptureMode == enmScreenCaptureMode.Screen)
        {
            bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
            CursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
        }
        else
        {
            var foregroundWindowsHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
            var rect = new Rect();
            GetWindowRect(foregroundWindowsHandle, ref rect);
            bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
            CursorPosition = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - rect.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - rect.Top);
        }

        var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Point CursorPosition
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to declare our own Rectangle structure rather than using System.Drawing.Rectangle? Is it only so that we can add an attribute? Do you know if we should do this for the Point structure too?

Comment: @Alex, I tried to replace my `Rect` with System `Rectangle`, but after that the function `GetWindowRect` returned wrong rectangle. Instead of `Right` and `Top`, it set `Width` and `Height` of output rectangle.

Comment: One caveat: Foreground window isn't necesarily the window of the application from which this gets called. For a single window WPF app you'd use `var thisWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;` instead

Answer (score 13):

KvanTTT's code worked great.  I extended it a bit to allow a little more flexibility on save format, as well as the ability to save by hWnd, .NET Control/Form.  You can get a bitmap or save to file, with a few options.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MosaiqPerformanceMonitor {
     public enum CaptureMode {
          Screen, Window
     }

     public static class ScreenCapturer {
          [DllImport("user32.dll")]
          private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

          [DllImport("user32.dll")]
          private static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

          [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
          private struct Rect {
                public int Left;
                public int Top;
                public int Right;
                public int Bottom;
          }

          [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
          public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

          /// <summary> Capture Active Window, Desktop, Window or Control by hWnd or .NET Contro/Form and save it to a specified file.  </summary>
          /// <param name="filename">Filename.
          /// <para>* If extension is omitted, it's calculated from the type of file</para>
          /// <para>* If path is omitted, defaults to %TEMP%</para>
          /// <para>* Use %NOW% to put a timestamp in the filename</para></param>
          /// <param name="mode">Optional. The default value is CaptureMode.Window.</param>
          /// <param name="format">Optional file save mode.  Default is PNG</param>
          public static void CaptureAndSave(string filename, CaptureMode mode = CaptureMode.Window, ImageFormat format = null) {
                ImageSave(filename, format, Capture(mode));
          }

          /// <summary> Capture a specific window (or control) and save it to a specified file.  </summary>
          /// <param name="filename">Filename.
          /// <para>* If extension is omitted, it's calculated from the type of file</para>
          /// <para>* If path is omitted, defaults to %TEMP%</para>
          /// <para>* Use %NOW% to put a timestamp in the filename</para></param>
          /// <param name="handle">hWnd (handle) of the window to capture</param>
          /// <param name="format">Optional file save mode.  Default is PNG</param>
          public static void CaptureAndSave(string filename, IntPtr handle, ImageFormat format = null) {
                ImageSave(filename, format, Capture(handle));
          }

          /// <summary> Capture a specific window (or control) and save it to a specified file.  </summary>
          /// <param name="filename">Filename.
          /// <para>* If extension is omitted, it's calculated from the type of file</para>
          /// <para>* If path is omitted, defaults to %TEMP%</para>
          /// <para>* Use %NOW% to put a timestamp in the filename</para></param>
          /// <param name="c">Object to capture</param>
          /// <param name="format">Optional file save mode.  Default is PNG</param>
          public static void CaptureAndSave(string filename, Control c, ImageFormat format = null) {
                ImageSave(filename, format, Capture(c));
          }
          /// <summary> Capture the active window (default) or the desktop and return it as a bitmap </summary>
          /// <param name="mode">Optional. The default value is CaptureMode.Window.</param>
          public static Bitmap Capture(CaptureMode mode = CaptureMode.Window) {
                return Capture(mode == CaptureMode.Screen ? GetDesktopWindow() : GetForegroundWindow());
          }

          /// <summary> Capture a .NET Control, Form, UserControl, etc. </summary>
          /// <param name="c">Object to capture</param>
          /// <returns> Bitmap of control's area </returns>
          public static Bitmap Capture(Control c) {
                return Capture(c.Handle);
          }


          /// <summary> Capture a specific window and return it as a bitmap </summary>
          /// <param name="handle">hWnd (handle) of the window to capture</param>
          public static Bitmap Capture(IntPtr handle) {
                Rectangle bounds;
                var rect = new Rect();
                GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);
                bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
                CursorPosition = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - rect.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - rect.Top);

                var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                     g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);

                return result;
          }

          /// <summary> Position of the cursor relative to the start of the capture </summary>
          public static Point CursorPosition;


          /// <summary> Save an image to a specific file </summary>
          /// <param name="filename">Filename.
          /// <para>* If extension is omitted, it's calculated from the type of file</para>
          /// <para>* If path is omitted, defaults to %TEMP%</para>
          /// <para>* Use %NOW% to put a timestamp in the filename</para></param>
          /// <param name="format">Optional file save mode.  Default is PNG</param>
          /// <param name="image">Image to save.  Usually a BitMap, but can be any
          /// Image.</param>
          static void ImageSave(string filename, ImageFormat format, Image image) {
                format = format ?? ImageFormat.Png;
                if (!filename.Contains("."))
                     filename = filename.Trim() + "." + format.ToString().ToLower();

                if (!filename.Contains(@"\"))
                     filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") ?? @"C:\Temp", filename);

                filename = filename.Replace("%NOW%", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd@hh.mm.ss"));
                image.Save(filename, format);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Top bit of code, got it working with no issues and it was just what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you use `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` to get the screenshot.

You can use [P/Invoke to GetForegroundWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetForegroundWindow.html) ([and then get its position and size](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.GetWindowOrgEx)) to determine which region you need to copy from.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the code from this question: [How can I save a screenshot directly to a file in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158151/how-can-i-save-screenshot-directly-to-a-file-in-windows)

Just change `WIN32_API.GetDesktopWindow()` to the Handle property of the window you want to capture.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use managed code: This will capture any window via the ProcessId.

I used the following to make the window active.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate(ProcessId);
Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
```

I used the print screen to capture a window.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%{PRTSC}");
Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
IDataObject objData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code :

```
            // Shot size = screen size
            Size shotSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;

            // the upper left point in the screen to start shot
            // 0,0 to get the shot from upper left point
            Point upperScreenPoint = new Point(0, 0);

            // the upper left point in the image to put the shot
            Point upperDestinationPoint = new Point(0, 0);

            // create image to get the shot in it
            Bitmap shot = new Bitmap(shotSize.Width, shotSize.Height);

            // new Graphics instance 
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(shot);

            // get the shot by Graphics class 
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(upperScreenPoint, upperDestinationPoint, shotSize);

            // return the image
            pictureBox1.Image = shot;
```

Answer (score 1):

A little tweak to method **static void ImageSave()** will grant you the option where to save it. Credit goes to Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx)

```
static void ImageSave(string filename, ImageFormat format, Image image, SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1)
    { 
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Enregistrer un image";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            // Saves the Image via a FileStream created by the OpenFile method.
            System.IO.FileStream fs =
               (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            // Saves the Image in the appropriate ImageFormat based upon the
            // File type selected in the dialog box.
            // NOTE that the FilterIndex property is one-based.
            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    image.Save(fs,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }

            fs.Close();
        }



    }
```

Your button_click event should be coded something like this...

```
private void btnScreenShot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();


        ScreenCapturer.CaptureAndSave(filename, mode, format, saveFileDialog1);

    }//
```

Answer (score 1):

Works if the Desktop scaling is set.

```
public class ScreenCapture
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Rect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

    public static Image CaptureDesktop()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(GetDesktopWindow());
    }

    public static Bitmap CaptureActiveWindow()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(GetForegroundWindow());
    }

    public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        var rect = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);
        GetScale getScale = new GetScale();
        var bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, (int)((rect.Right - rect.Left)* getScale.getScalingFactor()), (int)((rect.Bottom - rect.Top )* getScale.getScalingFactor()));
        var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here before taking the screenshot code will check whether scaling is set or not. If set then the factor is multiplied with the height and width of rectangle.

Comment: It looks like the `GetScale` class is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on ArsenMkrt's reply, but this one allows you to capture a control in your form (I'm writing a tool for example that has a WebBrowser control in it and want to capture just its display). Note the use of PointToScreen method:

```
//Project: WebCapture
//Filename: ScreenshotUtils.cs
//Author: George Birbilis (http://zoomicon.com)
//Version: 20130820

using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebCapture
{
  public static class ScreenshotUtils
  {

    public static Rectangle Offseted(this Rectangle r, Point p)
    {
      r.Offset(p);
      return r;
    }

    public static Bitmap GetScreenshot(this Control c)
    {
      return GetScreenshot(new Rectangle(c.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), c.Size));
    }

    public static Bitmap GetScreenshot(Rectangle bounds)
    {
      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
      return bitmap;
    }

    public const string DEFAULT_IMAGESAVEFILEDIALOG_TITLE = "Save image";
    public const string DEFAULT_IMAGESAVEFILEDIALOG_FILTER = "PNG Image (*.png)|*.png|JPEG Image (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Bitmap Image (*.bmp)|*.bmp|GIF Image (*.gif)|*.gif";

    public const string CUSTOMPLACES_COMPUTER = "0AC0837C-BBF8-452A-850D-79D08E667CA7";
    public const string CUSTOMPLACES_DESKTOP = "B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641";
    public const string CUSTOMPLACES_DOCUMENTS = "FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7";
    public const string CUSTOMPLACES_PICTURES = "33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB";
    public const string CUSTOMPLACES_PUBLICPICTURES = "B6EBFB86-6907-413C-9AF7-4FC2ABF07CC5";
    public const string CUSTOMPLACES_RECENT = "AE50C081-EBD2-438A-8655-8A092E34987A";

    public static SaveFileDialog GetImageSaveFileDialog(
      string title = DEFAULT_IMAGESAVEFILEDIALOG_TITLE, 
      string filter = DEFAULT_IMAGESAVEFILEDIALOG_FILTER)
    {
      SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();

      dialog.Title = title;
      dialog.Filter = filter;


      /* //this seems to throw error on Windows Server 2008 R2, must be for Windows Vista only
      dialog.CustomPlaces.Add(CUSTOMPLACES_COMPUTER);
      dialog.CustomPlaces.Add(CUSTOMPLACES_DESKTOP);
      dialog.CustomPlaces.Add(CUSTOMPLACES_DOCUMENTS);
      dialog.CustomPlaces.Add(CUSTOMPLACES_PICTURES);
      dialog.CustomPlaces.Add(CUSTOMPLACES_PUBLICPICTURES);
      dialog.CustomPlaces.Add(CUSTOMPLACES_RECENT);
      */

      return dialog;
    }

    public static void ShowSaveFileDialog(this Image image, IWin32Window owner = null)
    {
      using (SaveFileDialog dlg = GetImageSaveFileDialog())
        if (dlg.ShowDialog(owner) == DialogResult.OK)
          image.Save(dlg.FileName);
    }

  }
}
```

Having the Bitmap object you can just call Save on it

```
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser.GetScreenshot().Save("C://test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

The above assumes the GC will grab the bitmap, but maybe it's better to assign the result of someControl.getScreenshot() to a Bitmap variable, then dispose that variable manually when finished with each image, especially if you're doing this grabbing often (say you have a list of webpages you want to load and save screenshots of them):

```
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap bitmap = webBrowser.GetScreenshot();
  bitmap.ShowSaveFileDialog();
  bitmap.Dispose(); //release bitmap resources
}
```

Even better, could employ a using clause, which has the added benefit of releasing the bitmap resources even in case of an exception occuring inside the using (child) block:

```
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using(Bitmap bitmap = webBrowser.GetScreenshot())
    bitmap.ShowSaveFileDialog();
  //exit from using block will release bitmap resources even if exception occured
}
```

Update:

Now WebCapture tool is ClickOnce-deployed (http://gallery.clipflair.net/WebCapture) from the web (also has nice autoupdate support thanks to ClickOnce) and you can find its source code at https://github.com/Zoomicon/ClipFlair/tree/master/Server/Tools/WebCapture

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void ScreenCapFull_Clip(string strDestinationFolder, string strDestinationFile, bool bWriteToFile, bool bWriteToClipboard, out string strError)
    {
        strError = String.Empty;

        if (strDestinationFile.Trim() == String.Empty) // Sort of hokey
            bWriteToFile = false; //    strDestinationFile = "c:\\temp\\clip.jpg";

        int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
        int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
        int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
        int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

        // Create a bitmap of the appropriate size to receive the full-screen screenshot.
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
        {
            // Draw the screenshot into our bitmap.
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
            }

            //Save the screenshot as a Jpg image
            var uniqueFileName = strDestinationFile; // "C:\\temp\\a.Jpg";
            try
            {
                if(bWriteToFile == true)
                    bitmap.Save(uniqueFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strError = "Error: Could not write to file: " + uniqueFileName + "-" + ex.Message + "...";
            }

            if (bWriteToClipboard == false)
                return;

            try
            {
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Image = bitmap; //???
                                   //Put the image in a memorystream. VpaResult.VpaImage is a picturebox.
                                   //VpaResult.VpaImage.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                pb.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                DataObject m_data = new DataObject();
                m_data.SetData("PNG", true, ms);
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(m_data, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strError += "Error: Could not write to Clipboard: " + ex.Message + "...";
                strError = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }  // End public static void ScreenCapFull_Clip
```