# VB.NET Window Screen Capture (ALT+PRINTSCREEN)

Tags: .net, vb.net, screenshot

I found that code somewhere and I find it quite useful but I would like to find a way to make it work so it capture only the given window target. Maybe with a processID or Window Name. Even if that window is not active.

I do not want to make that window active but want to get a screen capture like if I was doing Alt+PrintScreen on it.

Here is the code that works for full Screen Capture

```
    Private bmpScreenShot As Bitmap
    Private gfxScreenshot As Graphics

    bmpScreenShot = New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

    gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenShot)
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

    bmpScreenShot.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png)
```

I use the Visual Basic 2008 Express

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture screenshot of active window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-capture-screenshot-of-active-window)
Instead of `this.Handle` (current window) you may insert a handle of any other window (using **WinAPI** functions like `FindWindow`)

Answer (score 1):

This works in vb.net2.0. I just used it.
[Here is the source code.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?385497-Easy-Screen-Capture-Class-Capture-Screen-Desktop-Region-Form-or-Controls)

```
    Dim SC As New ScreenShot.ScreenCapture

    'captures entire desktop straight to file
    SC.CaptureScreenToFile("c:\accops\test\desktop2.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it, though it's a hack, is this:

```
SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}")
Dim Screenshot As Image = Clipboard.GetImage()
Screenshot.Save("c:\ScreenShot.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the `Alt + Printscreen`, showing only front most application.

```
SendKeys.Send("%{PRTSC}")
```

Then continue the normal way:

```
Dim Screenshot As Image = Clipboard.GetImage()
Screenshot.Save("c:\ScreenShot.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the active-form.

```
Private Sub tsbCamera_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbCamera.Click
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
    DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height))
    Dim name As String = InputBox("Name it:")
    bm.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\ScreenShot\" & name & ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```