# How to Save The Whole Windows Form as Image? - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

[image: Windows Form that I wanted to save As Image]

Is it possible to actually save this windows form as image? like when the user clicked the save as image? If yes, Is it okay to provide me codes for this? Thank you.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563381/vb-net-window-screen-capture-altprintscreen

Comment: Do you just want to save the *contents* of the form, or do you also want to include the title bar and the menu bar?

Comment: Yes, I also want to include the title bar and the menu bar. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there will not be anyone providing code for you here.only guidance or some light to your solution will be given.

So as a light to the solution,look at this method supported by .NET.

[Control.DrawBitmap method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx)

you can use the method like :

```
 Dim frm = Form.ActiveForm
Using bmp = New Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height)
    frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
    bmp.Save("c:\temp\screenshot.png")
End Using
```

hope this provided a small input to the solution.

Comment: hi! thanks for the idea :) I've combined this idea with the video I watched on youtube. Thanks again!

Comment: This worked like a charm for a newcomer like me.