# Run WinForms control inside WebForms and take screenshot of it

Tags: asp.net, winforms, controls, screenshot

Like the title says, is it possible to run a winforms component inside a asp.net website and then take a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to [place a user control on a web page](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Place-Windows-Control-To-Web-Form.aspx) but my experience with it in the past were really bad.

I tried this back in 2005 and it worked on Internet Explorer only, and even in a well-defined intranet there were machines where it failed.

So I would vote against.

For the screenshot part, please see [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-capture-screenshot-of-active-window).

Comment: Actually I was just looking for a solution to run the control in code and then capture a screenshot of it and show it to the user (the later part is easy once I got the screenshot in memory).

Comment: So you are using the control only to take the screenshot of the website? Maybe it would be better to make a standalone Windows Forms application, use the `WebBrowser` control and then take a screenshot from the web browser?

Comment: I was thinking of using either Webkit.NET or GeckoFX to do that, yes. Both are webform-components so the solution would be to init the control in asp.net and then take a screenshot of it. And yes, I'm starting to think that I have to make a .net application and run it inside asp.net and take a screenshot of that. Would be more simple though to only use the component.

Comment: For which purpose do you need the screenshots?

Comment: Produce accurate screenshots of differnt websites to the users of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. The ASP.NET runtime won't let you create a Form within its sandbox. Access to the Graphics library is also tied to WinForms, so I doubt that will be much help.

I would take a look at WPF; the XAML markups for layout of controls can be rendered in a forms app or a web browser, allowing you to create a web control that looks like a windows form control.

Comment: I know that I have done this before (just can't find my example program) - I did a webpage that initiated a winform with som graffics in it (directx) and then took a screenshot of that form and showed it to the user via a ashx.