# Get image of any window without taking a screen shot?

Tags: c#, winapi, screenshot

I'm looking for a way to get a picture of the Main Window of a process without getting a screenshot of the whole desktop. I want to be able to get a picture of minimized windows and covered windows. Ideally I'd like to get this image as a `Bitmap` object for later manipulation.

I can already get the hwnd for the Main Window using `System.Diagnostics.Process`, where can I use that hwnd to get the image of the window? I do expect to need to use the WinAPI, I just don't know where.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-capture-screenshot-of-active-window

Comment: Exact duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-capture-screenshot-of-active-window. Second answer tells how to do it without screenshot

Comment: Shekhar_Pro: g.CopyFromScreen(...) is fundamentally a screenshot. It is not a duplicate and it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a memory DC.
Send the handle of that memory DC to the hWnd of the main window to a PRINT message to the window.

- http://www.pinvoke.net
  Great way to explore WINAPI and figure out how to call the different methods.

  http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/Csharp/cs_graphics/drawing/article.php/c6137
  This article shows how to create Memory DCs using pinvoke.