# Taking screen shot of a (remote) web page programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, screenshot

I'm trying to take screen shots of web pages programmatically. I may also require to take screen shots of full or partial page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: But does asp.net support WebBrowserControl?

Comment: You can look at this solution where you can find [a class that is responsible for making screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172478/taking-screenshot-of-aspx-page/5172606#5172606)

Comment: A related q/a: [How to fix a opacity bug with DrawToBitmap on WebBrowser Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21697048/1768303)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434156/webbrowser-drawtobitmap-other-methods) seems to cover capturing web pages - including alternatives to WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap. I guess once you've got the full page as an image you can manipulate that to get the partial page shot

Answer (score 4):

Check out webbrowser method

```
webBrowser1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bitmapRect);
```

for more complete example go [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/code140_Taking-Website-Screenshots-With-The-WebBrowser-Control.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `WebBrowser` control, and use the [VB PrintForm control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690938.aspx) to capture the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Rectangle region = new Rectangle(0, 0, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(region.Width, region.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
using (Graphics bitmapGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
bitmapGraphics.CopyFromScreen(region.Left, region.Top, 0, 0, region.Size);
bitmap.Save("location");
}
```

Source : http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2007/04/13/capture-screen-using-c-and-net-20/

Comment: I load remote websites programmatically using WebRequest and WebResponse. So I only have the markup and I dont render it in the screen.