# How to let the WebBroswer control process the page rendering?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

The solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828265/35150 works great with some pages.

I have a page where I still get blank page. The page uses ajax calls to load data and then render the data with a JS library. My guess that the browser doesn't get enough time to process all this (DocumentCompleted fires too early - I've seen that with other approaches.) How can I give the browser enough time to process?

Comment: Javascript executes completely asynchronously from any events you get from WebBrowser.  The only way you can possibly tell that it progressed to a certain point is by looking at side-effects, changes in the DOM that you check with a timer's Tick event.

Comment: @gerleim, I use `await Task.Delay()` for non-deterministic polling, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303). Some other [related stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303).