# DirectX, bouncing a directx rendering from a source hwnd to a new target hwnd

Tags: wpf, directx, webbrowser-control, ole, iwebbrowser2

I have a considerable challenging subject i'm trying to figure out.

Within WPF/WinForms I can create a WebBrowser component which has significant limitations, these would be drastically resolved/reduced if i can bounce the directx surface from the web browser control to a DirectX surface i have setup.

A few things to note:

1. The WebBrowser component hosts IWebBrowser2 OLE/ActiveX component in a "floating" window above existing content as a child window of the WPF window.
2. I know and can get (without hacks) the HWND of the floating window; and the sub-classed HWND's of the children which have the actual Internet Explorer component running.
3. I can confirm that the window is rendering with directX, but i do not have any handles to anything outside of a HWND. I do not know the surface its rendering to, the device, or anything else.

**What I've found as potential solutions:**

1. BitBlt the child window to a WPF surface to solve the problem; this is an option of last resort as it would require a timer to capture, and update the bitmap.  This seems wasteful and doesn't seem to be all that great.
2. The option to "Redirect" a HWND's directx surface has been noted as "trivial" by Microsoft Blog writers, but they never actually explain how. So there may be a non-directx non-gdi method thats more high-level that might work if anyone knows of one.
3. Use a swap chain to bounce the directx surface from the source WebBrowser HWND to the new target. This is my optimal choice; but its difficult to even begin since I do not have anything other than the HWND of the target. (I'm not limited to WPF, other tech such as OLE/COM/MFC/ATL/WinForms solutions are great!)
4. Is there a way to access the directx device from a OLE/COM object?...  Kind of a hail marry, using reflection/debuggers i can't seem to find any reference to it.  But this is also somewhat hack-y as i'm digging deep into the internals of the implementation.

Is there any pointers, hints or direction anyone can provide on how i might best accomplish this with the minimal "hackery" and maximum performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I really don't think you can force WebBrowser to render directly onto your custom DirectDraw surface. However, you might be able to provide a DD surface's HDC to draw onto.

If you want to play with this, WebBrowser ActiveX control implements [**Windowless** ActiveX Controls interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751970(v=vs.85).aspx#OC96_and_Windowless_). In theory, you could implement a windowless ActiveX host and use `IViewObject::Draw` to draw onto the DD surface's HDC. I cannot predict what the performance of this would be, but I doubt it would even closely approach the native DirectDraw performance of Trident rendering engine.

I also posted a [somewhat related code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828265/1768303) which uses `OleDraw` (which indirectly calls `IViewObject::Draw`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't able to dig into the OleDraw/IViewObject::Draw solution but you did actually give me a fairly interesting idea. BitBlt/StretchBlt are both hardware accelerated when using the same presents and using DirectX DC's.  With a little poking, i figured it would be faster to use the BitBlt idea that I had with GDI but instead with a DirectX surface, it works pretty well! You can see the results here: https://gist.github.com/trevorlinton/293f8d3de742ed7054e4 ultimately it doesn't seem like theres a solution that doesn't require using a timer :/.

Comment: @Trevor, regarding the timer, you may trying playing with `IAdviseSink` which the host would implement. The control should be calling when its representation changes.

Comment: I tried out using IAdviseSink, however it doesn't seem to post more than a notice when the control is created and is destroyed.  I suppose I can dig into more of the other MSHTML interfaces and see if theres something that might be a saving grace here.

Comment: Nevermind, the OLE object has IViewObjectPresentNotify interface to know when a rendering is about to occur. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg593035(v=vs.85).aspx