# How to get a image using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a component that uses the old WebBrowser control. The problem is that i use it to automate a process accessing a thirdy party page. The problem is that now i need to get a image, and this image is loaded by an extra GET request that i dont have control.

For example, i make a:

```
 webBrowser.Navigate("example.com");
```

And on the `DocumentCompleted` event i do some stuff. But when this event is fired, i see on fiddler that the browser make to extra `GETs` one to load a token and other to load a PNG. I need to get these two responses on the `DocumentCompleted` event. The image are like this on the html:

```
    <div id="container" data-url="exmple2Images.app"></div>
```

Ps: I cannot make another request by myself to `exmple2Images.app` because it refreshs the session and some cookies that are important.

Thanks.

Comment: Http Utility package is great: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: can you find the image in the WinInet cache? See your IE option for temp file location

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303) first, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21828265/1768303).