# Webbrowser Control how to change a window javascript property?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I need to change the `User-Agent` of my `webbrowser` control. But no using the overload of the `Navigating` method ( because the script get the user agent not from the header, but from the `window.navigator.appName` property. Is there a way to change this property in the webbrowser??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update: window.navigator should be a property you can overwrite via IDispatchEx (IExpando on the CLR runtime wrapper) in Javascript.
something like

```
var document=webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2;
var expando =(IExpando)document.parentWindow;
expando.RemoveProperty(expando.GetMember("navigator",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));
expando.AddProperty("navigator").SetValue(expando,myNavigator);
```

here myNavigator is a variable of a COM visible type that has an appName property.

not working:
[pinvoke UrlMkSetSessionOption](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/UrlMkGetSessionOption.html) and pass URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT as the option flag.

Comment: unfortunatelly it just send a header with the user agent.

Comment: Very nice answer, i can get the property navigator, but i cannot set the value of the navigator.appName yet. but im still trying

Comment: @ggui you have a race condition if the value is read during page load.

Comment: the expando.RemoveMember takes a MemberInfo as parameter, of system.Reflection.

Comment: Could you take a look in this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172010/how-to-get-a-image-using-webbrowser?noredirect=1#comment54152127_33172010