# asp.net screenshot

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to work on a new feature where a user can make a screenshot of the content in the browser via asp.net page and save it automatically as jpeg. Is there a example or someone can give me some idea how I can do that?
I will really appreciate.
Thanks in advance, Lazile

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking screenshot of ASPX page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172478/taking-screenshot-of-aspx-page)

Comment: What format do you need the screenshot in?

Comment: @n8wrl Thanks, I will check that link.  at ajax81 jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long and short of it is that you'll need to render the page on the server and take a picture of it.  Depending on your format needs, there are a variety of ways to do this.

Here's a link to a [tutorial](http://codegod.org/WebAppCodeGod/Screenshot-of-Webpage-with-ASP-NET-AID398.aspx) for getting a snapshot in jpg, bmp, png, etc.

If you need to get it to pdf format, I would recommend either using a program like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), or using the information from the tutorial and then pasting that image into a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/) out. It's javascript on the client side. It might meet your needs with some tweaking.
Edit: caveat is that it doesn't work in <IE9 as it uses HTML 5 canvas.

Comment: While this solution is very cool, IE doesn't support the method by which it generates the image.

Comment: yeah sorry, didn't realize my edit got cut off from the < sign. flashcanvas is supposed to let it work with IE