# C# Crystal Report problem and chart?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have 4 charts at my application drawn with custom code....
I also have a rdlc crystal report that outputs the data but not the chart...
What i have to do is to  add the chart at the report.
I can add a Chart object at the report but i dont know how to program it since it is in the report.. and i dont know how to refer to it via the reportviewer...

Only solution seems to be DataSet binding but i am too confused, it should be customized a lot... dont know if it is possible without writing source code..
Any ideas?
Please help this is a headache

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a chart now drawn in the report designer, I know no easy way of importing it to the report. My suggestion would be to export the data from the custom chart and import it back to the report into a chart drawn with the designer. As your chart is custom, I'm guessing that the imported data on the designer drawn chart won't exactly look like the original but that will at least properly present data.

Another option would be to put the custom chart on a form and taking a screenshot and placing that image on the actual report. The drawback on this would be the chart will appear still. This will be useful for scr shot: [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Comment: Well thats what i decided to do.. Chart supports saveImage method.Thats what i finnaly did...

Comment: Parhs, good find I didn't notice that Chart had a saveimage method, way better than taking screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Crstalreportusingvs2010.aspx?msg=3808568) explaining how charts works on Crystal Reports 2010 and what you need to do to create a basic report with a chart, including the C# code.

Based on it, you'll be able to understand how to improve with more complex charts.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to Subreport to show the chart.