# C# Crystal report export to PDF with Chart

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My Crystal report file contains data and one chart. When i am trying to export PDF from C# code, It does not export Chart. Showing Blank page for Chart.

I am using following code.

cryRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

Answer (score 0):

It seems similar with "Exportable" property, that all objects contain in FastReport.Net. Is there the same property in Crystal may be?

Answer (score 0):

[C# Crystal Report problem and chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145760/c-sharp-crystal-report-problem-and-chart)

It might be worth checking some of the previous answers provided on this question, that sounds to be fairly similar to your issue.