# Converting windows form in C# to PDF using PdfSharp

Tags: c#, windows, forms, pdf, pdf-conversion

I am trying to convert the current contents of a C# windows form to a pdf document.

I am using the PDFSharp dll to do the conversion, I am not sure of how to capture the windows form and convert it to a PDF. I gather I should use the `XGraphics.DrawImage()` method to copy the contents of the windows form.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window) and then pass the image into PDFSharp like:

```
var doc = new PdfDocument();

var oPage = new PDFPage();

doc.Pages.Add(oPage);
var xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage);
var img = XImage.FromFile(PATH_TO_IAMGE_CAPTURED_HERE);

xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);

doc.Save(YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE);
doc.Close();
```