# Using e.DrawString with iTextSharp to save as .pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

So I have my basic iTextSharp code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add();
        doc.Close();

    }
```

Now can I use

`e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text, label1.Font, Brushes.Black, 13, 13);`

with it??

Comment: I don't think so.is iTextSharp is must for you?If not,then PDfSharp would be good option to do things like that.Inform me if you want to do that.

Comment: @ridoy iTextSharp is not a must. Haw can I use e.Graphics.DrawString in PDFSharp?

Comment: Is your question "How can I write the contents of a WinForms label into a PDF?"

Answer (score 0):

Using `PdfDocument` you can do something like this..

```
  PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
  document.Info.Title = "Sample pdf using PDFsharp";

  PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

  XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

  XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic); //set your label1.Font here

  gfx.DrawString("Sample using PdfSharp!", font, XBrushes.Black, //you can use your label1.Text here
    new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
    XStringFormats.Center);

  const string filename = "sample.pdf";
  document.Save(filename);

  Process.Start(filename);
```

Here `XGraphics.DrawString()` acts like `Graphics.DrawString()` of `.NET`.

Comment: How can I use this to deaw the label or textbox?

Comment: Do you want to draw textbox/label or it's text? please clearly specify what things you want to do?

Comment: I have a windows form with labels and textboxes. I used e.Graphics.DrawString and  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle withe the  printDocument but now I would like to save it as pdf. I know I can use programs like  Bullzip PDF printer but I want it to be more simpel for the end user.

Comment: So you want to print your windows form as pdf with it's all content in a word?

Comment: Yes but not as a printscreen. I have some if statements like:  if (textBox72.Text == "0" && textBox80.Text == "0" && textBox40.Text == "0" .......

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813341/convert-windows-form-to-pdf-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618036/converting-windows-form-in-c-sharp-to-pdf-using-pdfsharp, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/465179/Convert-a-Windows-Form-to-PDF