# how to capture screen with angle parameter in c#

Tags: c#, .net, image

I've know how to capture screen in [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window), but I want to know how capture screen with certain angle. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "with certain angle"?

Comment: Do you mean with certain coordinates ?

Comment: "with certain angle" means may the edges of captured rectangle image may not be paralleled with the edges of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you capture the screen in `bitmap` and convert the bitmap into the rectangle shape you need?

Let's suppose you have the screen-capture as a bitmap `originalbitmap`

Now apply your rotations and transformations to the graphics context of your original image bitmap and store it in another bitmap `originalbitmap2`

Let's suppose you want to define and view a rectangular region of the rotated-bitmap. Store the rectangle information in  :  (say) `rect1`

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(<your width>,<your height>); //your final image bitmap
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
 g.DrawImage(originalbitmap2,0,0,rect1,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
 g.Dispose();
```

Now, you can use this bitmap!