# render html document

Tags: html, browser, document

I have html source code of pages and I need to do screen shots of how thoose pages would look in browser.

I don't want to use .net class WebBrowser or WebKit, because they are handling user events and  using them is really slow. I need to be able to visualize like 100 diffrent html documents in parallel.

Can any one recommend approach ?

Regards
Wojciech

Comment: These two posts might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You could open the html source in a browser e.g. on a server that creates your screenshots like this:

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
```

Then you can create a screenshot, e.g. with help of this post: [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

And after that you can save or stream the image to wherever you like. Hope this helps :)

Cheers!