# detecting when a window is updated using c# or win32 api

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm using `FindWindow` , and `SetForegroundWindow` from the `Win32 API` within via `pinvoke` C#. The window is a screen with scrolling text, thats updated randomly, I want to be able to detect when just the specific window has been updated. I'm new to C# how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetWindowText` from User32 if it's a specific control you are trying to monitor for changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx

Another method would be to take a screenshot of the window, and compare the last image with the current image to detect changes.

[Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Comment: i guess i could use spy++ to get the specific control

Comment: There are also functions that can be used to identify the controls that exist in a window.

Comment: that would be very useful what are they?

Comment: Here's an article you may find useful that talks about this:

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Windows/Enumerating_Windows/article.asp