# C# Screen capture of active window not appropriate

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to capture screen of active windows by following the method as answerd by ArsenMkrt below

[Please check ArsenMkrt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Entire screen could be captured and it is perfect, but when I try to cpature active window, screen is clipped out on all edges for ex, for a few windows title bar is missing, for others, active window along with some other background is captured. I like the method mentioned in that answer. I believe some changes are to be made in the CopyFromScreen method to bring the required perfection. Could anyone guide me in doing those chanegs?

Comment: Have a look at Wade Hatler's answer, it looks like the best one for you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11957567/1849109

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I just want to create it using .NET only classes and methods. However my application needs to call more and more Win32 API methods.