# Is there a way of taking a screenshot of the whole screen with White?

Tags: winforms, white-framework

Is there an API that would let me do it in http://teststack.github.com/White/?
I can't seem to find it.

Thanks

Pawel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The White.Repository project actually records the flow of your test, with screenshots but it is not very well documented and is not released on NuGet yet (it will be soon).

Personally I use this class we have put together from a bunch of sources and forget where I got it originally. This captures modal dialogues and other things that many of the other implementations didn't capture for some reason.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file.
/// </summary>
public class ScreenCapture
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int xDest, int yDest, int wDest, int hDest, IntPtr hdcSource, int xSrc, int ySrc, CopyPixelOperation rop);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDc);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DeleteDC(IntPtr hDc);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DeleteObject(IntPtr hDc);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr bmp);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr ptr);

    public Bitmap CaptureScreenShot()
    {
        var sz = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        var hDesk = GetDesktopWindow();
        var hSrce = GetWindowDC(hDesk);
        var hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hSrce);
        var hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hSrce, sz.Width, sz.Height);
        var hOldBmp = SelectObject(hDest, hBmp);
        BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, sz.Width, sz.Height, hSrce, 0, 0, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy | CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt);
        var bmp = Image.FromHbitmap(hBmp);
        SelectObject(hDest, hOldBmp);
        DeleteObject(hBmp);
        DeleteDC(hDest);
        ReleaseDC(hDesk, hSrce);

        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Then to consume

```
var sc = new ScreenCapture();
var bitmap = sc.CaptureScreenShot();
bitmap.Save(fileName + ".png"), ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old post. But I though can't hurt to update it. TestStack.White has these functions now:

```
//Takes a screenshot of the entire desktop, and saves it to disk
Desktop.TakeScreenshot("C:\\white-framework.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
//Captures a screenshot of the entire desktop, and returns the bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = Desktop.CaptureScreenshot();
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception during the TakeScreenshot call "a generic error occurred in GDI+". Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From looking through the code on GitHub, it doesn't appear to have an API for that (perhaps [add it as a feature request](https://github.com/TestStack/White/issues)?).

You can do it fairly simply yourself though using a combination of the [`Screen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class and [`Graphics.CopyFromScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yfzc507.aspx). There are some examples of how to capture the screen or the active window in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/).