# .NET Read Text from Label without Automation

Tags: c#, .net, testing, automation, .net-2.0

I am writing a C# application to perform testing automation of a legacy Win32 application. These tests require running applications, pressing buttons, and verify results by reading label text. My testing platform is limited to .NET 2.0, so my application cannot utilize `System.Windows.Automation`.

There is abundant information on how to interact with controls such as buttons using the WinAPI calls found in user32.dll. However, labels are not controls and do not have their own `hWnd` handles on which to utilize `WM_GETTEXT` message, and I have been unable to find how to extract their text.

I have used enterprise (expensive) testing software in the past which is able to identify labels as objects and read their text. The help files in that software vaguely explain how it is accomplished, and it is somehow done by monitoring Windows library calls.

So any ideas on how to capture label text in .NET, likely using Windows DLLs?

Comment: How do you know the labels aren't controls? Often, the labels are, usually with a window class of `Static`. Have you used Spy++ (from Visual Studio) or a similar tool to verify your assertion that the labels aren't controls?

Comment: I have tried Spy++ as well as the open source managedwinapi tools/libraries. These tools work on parts of the code that are .NET based - those labels are controls with hWnd handles. However, the vast majority of the code is really old fashioned C/C++ Win32 stuff. On those forms, the labels are not detectable as objects. I have even tried monitoring events, but cannot detect any event that occurs when the labels are changing.

Comment: The "really old fashioned C/C++ Win32 stuff" has window handles for labels as well. If those aren't showing up under Spy++, then the windows are using some sort of direct drawing on the window to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have no control over the code in the legacy Win32 application.

So, this is probably a terrible idea (no, it actually *is* a terrible idea). But as a last-ditch kludge to think of as a worst case scenario, you could 1) programmatically [take a screen capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window) of the active window, then 2) OCR the resulting image (maybe with [this](http://maniish.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/tesseract-ocr-library-successfully-compiled-in-window/)).