# Is it possible to clone the display from a secondary monitor and display it in a window on the primary monitor?

Tags: c#, windows, cloning, multiple-monitors, monitors

Like the title says, I am wondering where I should start with this idea. I want to be able to display the output from a secondary monitor in a window on the primary monitor, sort of like a Picture-In-Picture configuration.

The reason I want to do this is because I have a set up whereby I have two monitors, they are set up to extend the desktop but I cannot physically see what is being displayed on the second monitor while looking at the primary one.

I have been looking on MSDN about the screen class which may be a start. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx

Can anyone tell me where I should be starting with this or whether it is possible?

Comment: If you can't see the second monitor, how about disconnecting it and just moving the windows you keep there onto the main? I mean, the whole purpose of having more than one monitor is that *you should be able to see their content* and that *you want more screen estate*. Apparently you want to use main monitor screen estate to display the contents of a monitor you can't see. That's ... rather backwards.

Comment: Let's assume the secondary display is an information display located in another room instead of being hostile. It's a hack but I guess you could open a remote desktop connection to the computer and display the second screen in the client opened on display #1?

Comment: You assume correctly Hardev. Lasse, your assumption that I should be able to see the screen is incorrect. The secondary screen is used to display advertisments to customers in store and is mounted on the roof above the cash register... This is besides the point, I asked a specific question and responses like this are unproductive.

Answer (score 1):

I think i would try to capture a [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847637/take-screenshot-from-multiple-desktops-of-all-visible-applications-and-forms) and display it.
You have to do some experimentation to get just the other screens.