# I am trying to copy entire Form on button click event

Tags: c#

I am using a 
`Clipboard.SetText(textbox1.Text);`
in order to copy the contents of a text box to my clipboard, but I want to be able to copy the entire form text as well.

I tried using 
`Clipboard.SetText(FrmMain.Text);`

but it is not working, anyone have any thoughts or am i going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What is "entire form text"?

Comment: Do you want to copy from multiple text boxes?

Comment: I guess what you need is manually concatenating the contents of your form?

Comment: in other words I want to copy all text on the form, all labels, text boxes and combo boxes to paste formatted the same way as the form...this is for ticket notation when i document changes and repairs made.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to take a screenshot of the active window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window and copy the resulting image to the clipbard: https://www.google.nl/search?q=c%23+copy+picture+to+clipboard&oq=c%23+copy+picture+to+clipboard&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4486j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Add the following logic to a private method and call this method within button click handler.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Control item in Controls)
 {
      if (item is TextBox)
        {
           text.Append(item.Text);
           text.Append(',');
        }
 }

Clipboard.SetText(text.ToString());
```

**EDIT**

Without checking if the control type is `TextBox` you can get only textbox as follows,

```
foreach (Control item in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{    
   text.Append(item.Text);
   text.Append(',');                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the text from the form is static, you could always add it as a string to your statement

```
Clipboard.SetText("Your String" + Textbox1.Text);
```

Comment: Isn't this the same OP have mention in the question??

Comment: I did try that but it is asking for an object reference when i change the fields to static, i will post my code as an answer...

Comment: not this kind of static, DJ Olker meant "static" like "constant" I assume ;)

Comment: yeah, i cant post my code its too long and i cant answer my own question...(im new to this...)

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own method for getting the string from all controls.

```
private string GetFormText()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof (TextBox) ||
            control.GetType() == typeof (ComboBox) ||
            control.GetType() == typeof (Label))
        {
            String controlText = String.Format("{0}:{1}", control.Name, control.Text);
            sb.AppendLine(controlText);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

then you can save your form text like this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(this.GetFormText());
```

Comment: Don't forget RichTextBox :)

Comment: ok, this makes a ton more sense to me but it is still yelling at me when i call Clipboard.SetText(FrmMain.GetFormText()); looking for an object reference...

Comment: use this.GetFormText();