# Win7 screenshot programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linux, macos, windows-7

How do I make a screenshot programmatically in c# from several operating systems?

I have a application running on several systems. Mac Linux and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Windows,

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
this.imageDisplay.Image = img;
sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"D:\\ScreenShot1.png",ImageFormat.png);
```

follow the link for implementation

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/

Comment: This ScreenCapture class is part of a standard library?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco I forgot to add the link, actually it needs few API functions pls refer the link.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this my self but here is what I found online in a similer question.

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
// capture the screen and stores it in a image
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
```

Here is the question I got the information from
[Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Here is a reference to the site they got the answer from
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/

Hope this helps.

Edit: Here is another way that I found

```
private Bitmap Screenshot()
{
    //Create a bitmap with the same dimensions like the screen
    Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width,
                                         SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);

    //Create graphics object from bitmap
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screen);

    //Paint the screen on the bitmap
    g.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,
                             SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,
                             0, 0, screen.Size);
    g.Dispose();

    //return bitmap object / screenshot
    return screen;
}
```

Reference found here http://en.code-bude.net/2012/12/27/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-csharp/