# How to capture screenshot without user32.dll which is unmanaged code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, screenshot

**Overview**
I am trying to capture a screenshot of external application and load the image to a .NET PictureBox.

**user32.dll Unmanaged Code**
There are a bunch of examples using user32.dll an I am looking for a .NET answer that does not use the user32.dll file.

App #1
I have provided sample code below that I am using for demonstration purposes. When the program is executed, it parses Processes and saves ones with valid window titles to the drop-down list.

When you select the app name from the drop-down list and click the button, it will try to capture the screenshot app and load into the .NET PictureBox.

[image: App #1] [image: App #2]

Form1.cs

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            Dictionary<string, IntPtr> apps = new Dictionary<string, IntPtr>();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                        continue;

                    apps.Add(process.MainWindowTitle, process.MainWindowHandle);
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(process.MainWindowTitle);
                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                IntPtr intptr = apps[comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString()];

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(intptr);

                // get width and height of app #2
                int width = (int)g.VisibleClipBounds.Width;
                int height = (int)g.VisibleClipBounds.Height;

                Size s = new Size(width, height);

                // create new bitmap
                Bitmap wincapture = new Bitmap(width, height, g);

                // code tried.
                //g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(width, height));
                //g.DrawImage(wincapture, 0, 0, width, height);

                // once App #2 has been captured, show image in picture box.
                pictureBox1.Image = wincapture;
            }
        }
    }
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```cs
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
    {
        partial class Form1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
                this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // pictureBox1
                // 
                this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
                this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
                this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(267, 183);
                this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
                // 
                // button1
                // 
                this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 227);
                this.button1.Name = "button1";
                this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(82, 23);
                this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
                this.button1.Text = "View Ext App";
                this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
                // 
                // comboBox1
                // 
                this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
                this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 202);
                this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
                this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(267, 21);
                this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 3;
                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 256);
                this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
                this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
                this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.Text = "App #1";
                ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            #endregion

            private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your current code do? Why don't you want to use unmanaged functions? Looks like at least you need GetWindowRect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture screenshot of active window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Comment: I was hoping that the code would capture the window?

`Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(intptr);`

Not sure how to copy to bitmap.

Comment: NightOwl, that question is from **2009** and uses **unmanaged code**.  I was hoping that with .NET 4, we might have some new classes.

Comment: @CodeCaster When code is executed, the Form1() method cycles through every Window process and adds them to the drop-down list which has a window title. When you select a title from the drop-down list and press the button it will try to take a screenshot and load the image into the PictureBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I came up with to take a screenshot of an application without using user32.dll.

---

To make the app active, and wait for 20 to make sure it has completed.

```cs
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate(ProcessId);
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
```

To capture the active window, I used the following. Added a delay of 200, then convert the clipboard object to an image.

```cs
    SendKeys.SendWait("%{PRTSC}");
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    IDataObject objData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```