# Screenshot in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to take screen shot in C# but its not working.

```
protected void btnscreenshot_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(GenerateThumbnail);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
private void GenerateThumbnail()
{
    WebBrowser webrowse = new WebBrowser();
    webrowse.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    webrowse.AllowNavigation = true;
    webrowse.Navigate("www.mindfiresolutions.com");
    //webrowse.Width = 1024;
    //webrowse.Height = 768;
    webrowse.Width = 1024;
    webrowse.Height = 1024;
    webrowse.DocumentCompleted += webbrowse_DocumentCompleted;
    while (webrowse.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
private void webbrowse_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
                    WebBrowser webrowse = sender as WebBrowser;
    //Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webrowse.Width, webrowse.Height);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1024, 1024);
    webrowse.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, webrowse.Bounds);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Data/Screen.jpeg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] strbytes = stream.ToArray();
    imgscreenshot.Visible = true;
    imgscreenshot.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(strbytes);
    string dd = imgscreenshot.ImageUrl;
}
```

Comment: OK, so what's happening with that code ? What have you tried to debug that problem already ?

Comment: its giving  me blank white image.

Comment: what have you done!! removed all the code??

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code from this **[SOURCE](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/)**

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
// capture entire screen, and save it to a file
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
this.imageDisplay.Image = img;
// capture this window, and save it
sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"C:\\temp2.gif",ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Or alternatively you can do as below:

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
         g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

for capturing current window

```
 Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
 using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
 {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left,bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("C://test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 }
```

**[SO SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)**

**UPDATE:**

I've created a dummy project and `onclick` of a `button` I was capturing `screenshot` and below is the sample code:

In **`default.aspx`**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCapture" runat="server" OnClick="btnCapture_Click" Text="Capture Screen"/>
```

**`default.aspx.cs`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using ScreenCaptureDemo;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Content/test.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg); //Change Content to any folder name you desire
        }
    }
}
```

and below is the image I got:

[image: Image Captured]

Comment: it tried  but on server it is not working                                       
   
            String filepath = Server.MapPath(StatePath);
            Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(xheight, xwidth, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            System.Drawing.Rectangle captureRectangle = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;//capture our Current Screen
            Graphics captureGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(captureBitmap); //Creating a New Graphics Object
            captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(182, 207, 0, 0, captureRectangle.Size);
            captureBitmap.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: which method you tried?? Any exceptions you are getting??

Comment: i m not getting but i think this line not working on server captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(182, 207, 0, 0, captureRectangle.Size); captureBitmap.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: which method you are trying?? did you try first method??

Comment: @KratikaSharma.. Updated the answer!! Check and let me know.. :)

Comment: i have tried all above methods but nothing is working.

Comment: Can you post your aspx page's button control or complete aspx page?? because the above update whatever I've given worked for me and then I posted it here!!

Comment: please have a look i already have pasted it. is there any other way  to send my test pages?

Comment: you have pasted `.cs` code behind file codes.. I asked designer code!!

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div id="form1" runat="server">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnscreenshot" Text="Take Screenshot" runat="server" OnClick="btnscreenshot_click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<asp:Image ID="imgscreenshot" runat="server" Visible = "false" Height="1100" Width="1500" />
</div>


</asp:Content>

Comment: its working on local host but when i uploaded it on server its not working.

Comment: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid

Comment: [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid]

Comment: [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid]                                    System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation) +653
   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize) +35
   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Point upperLeftSource, Point upperLeftDestination, Size blockRegionSize) +54
   testCapture.CaptureMy() in d:\WeatherPortal\testCapture.aspx.cs:121

Comment: @KrathikaSharma.. That's because there is no screen on the server.  It worked on your development platform because the server was your client screen. Now since you deployed your code into some other server, it will not capture and it is explained **[here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74e789ea-160b-4b89-8296-3274d1bff1de/copyfromscreen-giving-error-in-server?forum=csharplanguage)** . If you want to capture the clients screen, it will be with javascript code. Alternatively you can visit **[here](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/11/capturing-the-screen-image-using-c/)**

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding.. :)

Comment: link  u reffered is great but there is a problem on local its fine but on server its saving blank(black ) image..

Comment: @KratikaSharma. I have explained why you cannot achieve that in my previous comments!!

Comment: i was asking because u reffered me http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/11/capturing-the-screen-image-using-c/

Comment: so i thought u might have any idea.. thanks for ur support until now