# Why is my application telling me that my clipboard is empty when clearly it's not?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, screenshot, clipboard

Im trying to take a screenshot of my screen with a console application and then save it to my desktop but for some reason.. its telling me that my clipboard is empty when clearly its not.. If you check the code you can see that I press PrintScreen and when you do that it saves it to the clipboard.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScreenshotConsole
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            screenshot();
            Console.WriteLine("Printescreened");
            saveScreenshot();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static void screenshot()
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("{PRTSC}");
        }

        static void saveScreenshot()
        {
            //string path;
            //path = "%AppData%\\Sys32.png"; // collection of paths
            //path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage() == true)
            {
                Image image = (Image)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                image.Save("image.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Clipboard empty.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure sending prtsc works? What happens when you try to paste in paint?

Comment: I'm 100% sure it works, if I only call the printscreen method it printscreens and I can paste it in paint.

Comment: There are [better ways to capture a screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761) than using the clipboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will take some time to screenshot, so you shoud add a delay after pressing `{PRTSC}`:

```
static void screenshot()
{
    SendKeys.SendWait("{PRTSC}");
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

### UPDATE

OK, I figured it out, add `STAThreadAttribute` to your main method:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        screenshot();
        Console.WriteLine("Printescreened");
        saveScreenshot();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

MSDN says that:

> The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.

[More detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.containsimage(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @GooberS.Johnsson SEE UPDATE

Comment: Nvm it saves to the directory where it runs from, how would I change that?

Comment: The image will be saved in "current folder", which will be same as your EXE file by default. It's better to  specify an absolute path: `image.Save(@"d:\image.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Comment: How would I specify the path?

Comment: Oh I should of thought of that! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help you:)