# Winform: Export Graph with SaveImage Including Axes and Titles

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am currently using:

```
chart.SaveImage(exportData.FileName.ToString(),System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

to save a chart in a windows form as a .png file. Currently running into the issue that the chart is lacking axes and a title, etc. The images show the graph with data in Visual Studio and the saved image. As you can see, I am missing the axes and title in the saved image. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Graph in visual studio:
[image: Graph in visual studio]

Graph exported through SaveImage:
[image: Graph exported through SaveImage 2]

Comment: You can try and take a [screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use DrawToBitmap method. You also be able to add custom drawings and text on your chart canvas:

```
using (Bitmap im = new Bitmap(chart1.Width, chart1.Height))
{                
    chart1.DrawToBitmap(im, new Rectangle(0, 0, chart1.Width, chart1.Height));
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(im))
    {
        gr.DrawString("Test", 
            new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold), 
            new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new PointF(10, 10));
    }
    im.Save(path);                                    
}
```

This code is producing that image:
[image]