# How to capture active windows on desktop by vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, image, graphics, screenshot

I'm using this code to capture desktop

```
Private Function cc() As Bitmap
    Dim s As Screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen
    Dim img As New Bitmap(s.Bounds.Width, s.Bounds.Height)
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    gr.CopyFromScreen(s.Bounds.Location, Point.Empty, s.Bounds.Size)
    Return img
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = cc()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But now I want to capture only the active screen, how can I do that?

Regards,,,,,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1163770/1271037

Comment: lomed! How to Capture screenshot of active windows by vb.net not by c#

Answer (score 3):

for copy active window from our application, Just check the position and size of the window and reduced the copying to this rectangle:

```
Public Sub ScreenCopy(Optional file As String = "d:\test.jpg")
    Dim bounds = Me.Bounds
    Using bitmap As New Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height)

        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
            g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size)
        End Using

        bitmap.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Process.Start(file) ' for test purposes
    End Using
End Sub
```

for copy current active window even is not part of our application you need use an api for detect his size and location.

for this use this class (credit: @KvanTTT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9087955/1271037)

```
Class ScreenCapturer
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef rect As Rect) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure Rect
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Function Capture(Optional activeWindowOnly As Boolean = True) As Bitmap
        Dim bounds As Rectangle

        If Not activeWindowOnly Then
            bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty)
            CursorPosition = Cursor.Position
        Else
            Dim foregroundWindowsHandle = GetForegroundWindow()
            Dim rect = New Rect()
            GetWindowRect(foregroundWindowsHandle, rect)
            bounds = New Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top)
            CursorPosition = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - rect.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - rect.Top)
        End If

        Dim result = New Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height)

        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(result)
            g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size)
        End Using

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Property CursorPosition() As Point

End Class
```

how to use:

```
Public Sub ScreenCopy(Optional file As String = "d:\test.jpg")
    Dim sc = New ScreenCapturer()

    Using bitmap = sc.Capture()
        bitmap.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Process.Start(file) ' for test purposes
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Only a small change in syntax for VB.net regarding the DLL import:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetForegroundWindow")> Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
 End Function

 <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowRect")> Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef rect As Rect) As IntPtr
  End Function
```