# WPF UI to Screenshots

Tags: c#, sql, xml, wpf, screenshot

I have a WPF application which has a toolbox with items same as Visual Studio. These items can be dragged on to the gird and configured. Each item has its own configuration i.e., different textboxes, dropdowns etc. Similar to Visio user will connects items if required (two or more). We call this as a Playlist (collections of items with different configurations).

I have a requirement to present the configuration of a playlist in a report.  The customer will be using this playlist report to recreate the playlist.

All configurations are saved in XML. I am able to deserialise the XML and show it in the report but ideally the customer would like screenshots of each item in the report or some other format.

How can i achieve it? Sorry if it is a very wide question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window should answer your question I think

Comment: Are you wanting to do this programmatically - or would just Alt-PrtScn (with application active) & pasting into your report be what you want.

Comment: May be create a RDL report from the XML?  Read the xml into a DataTable and then go from DataTable to RDL.

Comment: @PaulF - I would like user to select a playlist and press a button and all screenshots are captured and perhaps stored in the database as images. I can then read these images in my report.

Comment: @jdweng -  How do you mean? Use XML as a datasource? As I mentioned in my question I already have a working report which deserialises the xml and shows in the report but it just tabluar and user would like screenshots instead.

Comment: The RDL report will produce a format webpage with the results.

Comment: @jdweng - Sorry still don't get you. Can you give me an example or ask me if you do not understand the question. Cheers.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/report-datasets-ssrs

Comment: @jdweng - As I have mentioned a few times, I already have a report with has datasets which are derived from XML however I have a requirement for Screenshots hence the question. Sorry If it was confusing for you.