# WPF: take a shot of a Visual during an animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a WPF control that displays many moving visual elements, using animations.
I would like to take "pictures" of it at certain times, during the animation: something like translate a WPF "movie" to an animated GIF.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Capture the screen? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window

Comment: I believe it should be possible to pause animation (storyboard) and render visual into bitmap.

Comment: @mm8 Well... yes. I possibly would like to do something more WPF-oriented, like to retrieve a vector Visual at particular instants

Comment: @Sinatr : yes... how?

Comment: @Starnutoditopo, by ... googling of course! You show no attempt, so I thought you stuck with ideas.