# Windows application (Smart Device Project). How to capture Screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, smart-device

I just want to capture the screen in `.Net Framework 2.0` with Smart Device application.

Not working:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screen);
g.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X, 
                 SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,0, 0, screen.Size);
```

and

```
this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
```

the above functions are not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of  [Capture screenshot of active window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Comment: With `.Net Framework 2.0` do you actually mean the full (ancient) Framework or `.Net Standard 2.0`? Or `.Net Core 2.0`? In `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screen);`, what is `screen`? Are you sure it can work well with `VirtualScreen.Location`?

Comment: .Net Framework 2.0 with Smart Device Windows CE 5.0 Project.