# C# ScreenCapture

Tags: c#, screenshot

I am trying to capture the screen using Visual Studio 12 (sorry, we have to use 12) cand C#.
I found an algorithm here: [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

```
 ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
```

I tried this and got an error message that the type or namespace is not found.
This is not unexpected.  I figured I just need another "using..." statement up at the top.
I tried to do a search for which package to do a "using" on to get ScreenCapture() but I come up empty handed.  Does anyone know?

Comment: If you were looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.screencapture - it's only available on Win mobile.

Comment: Follow the link on the top answer (from the question you linked).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.screencapture) you need to use `Windows.Media.Capture`. Please note that

> Important
>
> The ScreenCapture feature is only supported for mobile devices running Windows Phone 8.1. This API is not supported on Windows 10.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1163770/1118978) which works on all windows desktop platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably giving you an error around `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

You need to add the reference of the DLL System.Runtime.InteropServices

Answer (score 0):

This lib doesn't seem to exist on NuGet. However, you can find it at [Developer Fusion](https://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/).

The downloads section only includes a zip file with the following class, that you can copy-paste in your VS Project

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ScreenShotDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file.
    /// </summary>
    public class ScreenCapture
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureScreen() 
        {
            return CaptureWindow( User32.GetDesktopWindow() );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
            // get the size
            User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
            User32.GetWindowRect(handle,ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc,width,height); 
            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest,hBitmap);
            // bitblt over
            GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest,0,0,width,height,hdcSrc,0,0,GDI32.SRCCOPY);
            // restore selection
            GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest,hOld);
            // clean up 
            GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            User32.ReleaseDC(handle,hdcSrc);

            // get a .NET image object for it
            Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
            // free up the Bitmap object
            GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

            return img;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of a specific window, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle"></param>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format) 
        {
            Image img = CaptureWindow(handle);
            img.Save(filename,format);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of the entire desktop, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format) 
        {
            Image img = CaptureScreen();
            img.Save(filename,format);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class GDI32
        {

            public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter

            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject,int nXDest,int nYDest,
                int nWidth,int nHeight,IntPtr hObjectSource,
                int nXSrc,int nYSrc,int dwRop);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC,int nWidth, 
                int nHeight);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC,IntPtr hObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class User32
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int left;
                public int top;
                public int right;
                public int bottom;
            }

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd,IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd,ref RECT rect);

        }


    }
}
```