# can't capture Full Screen image ?? (with taskbar and any other open windows)

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a problem with this code :

i need to screenshot the full screen that i see with all things (taskbar, anything open).

my code is just giving me a cropped pic of just one window [image: (like this pic)]

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);

graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
bitmap.Save("D://Changes.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: What's with all those tags? Is this a Winform, WPF or UWP app? Tag accordingly

Comment: @Martheen yes it s a **Winform**.

Comment: Then remove your asp.net tags

Comment: Unable to replicate in my machine. Try creating a blank new winform project and only include the snippet in your question, if it still doesn't work, check your OS configuration.

Comment: Try this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window

Comment: @NaderKhazai   i have a problem with this line ``` this.imageDisplay.Image = img;```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your display settings are set to 125% (or higher) zoom.

Your application isn't DPI aware. You can correct that by [updating your application's manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process).

If that doesn't work for you (or you'd rather not use the manifest), you can pinvoke `GetDeviceCaps` API to get the correct width and height for `CopyFromScreen`.

Here are your native definitions:

```
private static class Win32Native
{
    public const int DESKTOPVERTRES = 0x75;
    public const int DESKTOPHORZRES = 0x76;

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hDC, int index);
}
```

And you'd call it as so:

```
int width, height;
using(var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    var hDC = g.GetHdc();
    width = Win32Native.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, Win32Native.DESKTOPHORZRES);
    height = Win32Native.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, Win32Native.DESKTOPVERTRES);
    g.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
}

using (var img = new Bitmap(width, height))
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, img.Size);
    }
    img.Save(@"C:\users\andy\desktop\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```