How to take screenshot of the browser including the URL and tabs using Selenium and C#
How to take screenshot of the browser including the URL and tabs using Selenium and C#?
This is how the screenshots look today

This is how the screenshots will look after change

The difference is - you see the line of the URL and the tabs
Any ideas on how to tackle this?
my code:
public string TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver)
{
   var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
   screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"C:\projects\screenshot.png");
   return screenshot.AsBase64EncodedString;
}

Selenium.Support 4.18.1
Selenium.WebDriver 4.18.1

use native code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window

Why do you want to include the address bar? You already know the current page's URL. If you want to store it as extra information along with the picture you can modify the picture with an image processing library (even System.Graphics if you're on .NET Framework) and write the URL or any other information as text. You could also add information to an image as metadata

It is not possible to do it with Selenium WebDriver. The maximum you can get is a full webpage within the browser's viewpoint, and as of today, past Selenium 4 it is only supported by FirefoxDriver class with the method getFullPageScreenshotAs. Example for Java:
File fullScreenshot
=((FirefoxDriver)driver).getFullPageScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

