# Graphics.CopyFromScreen() is capturing blank for particular application

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, snapshot, system.drawing.graphics

I am developing a .NET winforms application which has to capture a snapshot.

For this I have used `System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen` method which works fine but when I tries to capture screenshot of particular application (Oracle EBS) then it captures blank.

It captures all images well but only when Oracle ERP is tried to be captured it returns blank white.

```
graphics = Graphics.FromImage(CaptureBMP);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
CaptureBMP.Save(@"C:\Temp\printscreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It should capture Oracle ERP also in the picture

Comment: I think it might be an issue related to user permissions under which the Oracle ERP is running.

Comment: Does print screen button work?

Comment: yes, that works well and snipping tool also captures it correctly.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14135239/10927863) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158171/10927863) maybe it can fix your problem too